# How to sort a list using vue on-click and add an arrow in column using v-bind?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want the data is sorted in ascending/descending order when I click the corresponding column. Also, I need an arrow after the column to represent the order. I'm stuck in using vue on-click build a function to sort a list and using v-bind to add an arrow. What should I do with my vue/css/html??
Here is my html

```
     <div id="app">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr></tr>
            <th v-for="(header, key) in column" :key="key" v-on:click="sortTable(key)">{{ header }}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
            <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.phone }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

and my js

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    column: {
      id: "ID",
      name: "Full Name",
      phone: "Phone",
    },
    rows: [],
    sortColumn: null,
    sortOrder: "asc",
  },
  computed: {
    sortedRows() {
      if (!this.sortColumn) {
        return this.rows;
      }
      return this.rows.slice().sort((a, b) => {
        const aValue = a[this.sortColumn];
        const bValue = b[this.sortColumn];
        if (typeof aValue === "string") {
          return (
            aValue.localeCompare(bValue) * (this.sortOrder === "asc" ? 1 : -1)
          );
        }
        return (aValue - bValue) * (this.sortOrder === "asc" ? 1 : -1);
      });
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      const finalRes = await response.json();
      this.rows = finalRes;
    },
    sortTable(key) {
      if (key == this.sortColumn) {
        this.sortOrder = this.sortOrder === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
      } else {
        this.sortColumn = key;
      }
      alert(this.sortColumn);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
    this.sortTable(key);
  },
});
```

CSS:

```
table {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #444777;
  margin: 10px;
}

table th {
  background: #444777;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 30px;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 2px solid #444777;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #d4d8f9;
}
```

My expected outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two split up your problem into two problems.

### Class binding

You can add a class with a different syntax

```
<div :class="{'nameClass': condition}"></div>
```

In you case it would be something like:

```
<div :class="{sortDirection: sortBy === header}"></div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

### Sorting

You started the right way. But you don't sort anything in your method.
You need three conditions in a sort. Bigger, smaller and the same.

```
this.rows.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x[sortBy] < y[sortBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (x[sortBy] > y[sortBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

For both solutions there might be some small changes, but I hope the concept is clear :)

Comment: Should I put it in computed? and what I should code in the methods part? Sorry but I am confused how to build this function with v-on:click